# Messaging/Events vs. Traditional Method calls

Tags: c++, objective-c, methods, messaging

I recently had a project in my programming languages class in which I was to research and learn Objective-C in order to give a presentation to the class explaining the language. My professor suggested that I focus on some differences between Objective-C and C++.

One of the differences that I found was that Objective-C uses messaging from Smalltalk which seems to be very similar to Events in vb.net (vb.net and Java are my most fluent languages). Whereas C++ uses traditional Pass & Return method calls. I understand the differences between these (I think).

My question is, what are the benefits of messaging over traditional method calls and vice-versa? It seems like messaging may be better for multi-threading but I would like a more educated/experienced answer on this subject.

Comment: You compare eggs and chickens. Messaging is built on top of function calls anyway, it is just a higher level of abstraction. Not to mention that not everything in Objective-C is based on messaging, you can pretty much call a function or method, too. Especially when dealing with C or C++...

Comment: Ahh, I had read that it was possible to write just C and it would compile using an Objective-C compiler. But one of the sites I found made it sound like Objective-C was strictly messaging. This contradiction is what got me wondering :). Thanks for this, helps alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vlad mentioned in the comments, messaging doesn't compare directly to function calls because messaging is a system that is built on top of calls.  The reason you would use messaging is to further decouple your consumer (the caller) from your producer (callee).

When you make function calls, you need to have some kind of reference to the object you are calling. One way to minimize coupling is to use interfaces, but even in that case, there's still a direct link between the two classes.

With messaging, you can setup your architecture so that the caller doesn't even know where the real producer lives. He can simply send a message and wait for a response. Since a message is a self-contained object, they are easily serialized or simply passed from one proxy to another until someone eventually handles them and responds.

Another advantage of messaging is with workload balancing.  You could have a message queue and a pool of producers (in simplest case a thread pool). When a message arrives, on multicore machine, you could have multiple messages being handled concurrently.

Messaging architecture is also very popular with threading and asynchronous programming models. Even in the cases where you always have a direct reference to a producer, if you make a function call, you are blocked until you return. But if you send a message, you can continue working and eventually get a response. There are other alternatives such as Windows OVERLAPPED pattern and using callbacks and getting response on different threads. In this respect, messaging is one of several different patterns for performing asynchronous work, but it is one of the better and more widely accepted ones.

Comment: So messaging is basically a way to increase abstraction and security?

Comment: not sure about "security" but definitely higher abstraction layer, higher degree of decoupling and higher flexibility because you can do all kinds of crazy things with messages, since they are objects (e.g. save them to disk and continue working after reboot)

Comment: Are there any performance benefits of messaging? One site said that the initial message takes about 3 times longer than a C++ method call, but subsequent messages are actually faster. Is this why Objective-C objects tend to be more self-containing than C++ objects?

Comment: Messages themselves are not about performance. Making a simple function call itself WILL ALWAYS be faster than sending a message. But you need to put things in perspective. Once your message handling code has real implementation, what percentage of time do you think it'll take to get to your message handler vs. how much time you spend inside message handler.  To put things in terms of relative numbers: function call=1, message call=10(or 3, whatever), processing function or message call = 1000.  However, messaging is a great way to architect your software to take advantage of multiple cores...

Comment: ... so even though each call takes a little bit longer, you can handle multiple client requests simultaneously

Comment: Ahh, ok. I'm a full time student at the moment and a part time developer at a small company (that doesn't make the greatest use of the latest concepts) so I haven't had a whole lot of experience with threading or customer/client interaction. This helps alot. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Well this website goes over your question and alot more about differences between the two programming languages. I couldn't find anything specifically mentioning the benefits of messaging over traditional messages, but the author does a really good summary of the main concepts, which may help you solve your own question.

Here is an example of a section that I think you would really like because it states many important things that would be good on your presentation on Objective c **vs** c++

------------------------------------------**Philosophy of Each Language**------------------------------------------------

Think of Objective-C objects like a factory, and C++ objects like a home business. Objective-C objects tend to be large, self contained, and do everything imaginable. C++ objects tend to be small and to the point. C++ objects also tend to come in groups, where Objective-C objects tend to be more standalone. This does not mean that there can't be small Objective-C objects and large C++ objects, it only means that the trend is for Objective-C objects to be large, standalone objects and C++ objects to be small and dependent on one another.

When programming in C++, each and every concept, no matter how small, should get its own class. Applications typically have hundreds, if not thousands of classes, each one small, and all interconnected. This can lead to name collisions, but C++ has solved some of these problems by using NameSpaces. Even without NameSpaces, C++ can avoid name collisions by including only needed header files. Two classes can have the same name if they are private and never included by the same file.

Objective-C objects should be able to stand on their own. There are no private objects, only one name space, and object names are resolved at runtime. Having thousands of Objective-C objects is asking for trouble.

C++, with its zero overhead for non-virtual classes, encourages programmers to subclass ints, rects, and any other data structure. Writing a little bit of code can give range checking, type checking, value checking, or any other kind of checking imaginable. Objective-C has a lot of overhead for an object, and there is no operator overloading. It is not practical to have Objective-C classes for rects, ints, or other small data structures.

Despite many applications having been written in C++, and C++ having many features over Objective-C, I find writing applications in Objective-C much easier and faster than writing the same applications in C++. One of the biggest reasons for this is the number of objects found in an application. In Objective-C, having less than 100 objects in an application lets me keep the entire structure of the program in my head. In C++, where each concept is its own object, I am constantly looking for which object contains the functionality I'm looking for.

Another reason why Objective-C is faster to develop in is that it is a simpler language. I have seen programmers spend days trying to get the syntax of an esoteric C++ function just right. Objective-C does not have as many areas where language lawyers thrive. The worst part of C++'s esoteric syntax is other programmers might not be able to understand some of the more complex C++ code.

The biggest reason for the faster developement time is the self-contained object. Objective-C objects tend to be self-contained, so if you need functionality, you only need to include that one object, or occasionally a small number of related objects. C++ objects, on the other hand, tend to come in groups. Each time you want to include functionality from an object, you are likely required to include an additional 10-20 objects.

All this and more [here](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.13/13.03/CandObjectiveCCompared/index.html)

Comment: This was actually one of the articles that I referenced in my presentation but as you said earlier, it does not really address reasons why you would use one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth reading the wikipedia page about [Objective C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C), particularly the section [about messaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Messages).

Bear in mind that Objective C is built on top of, and hence is a superset of, C. In Objective C you can lapse into traditional C coding and function calls, as well as using messaging.

A crucial difference between Objective C messaging and function calls in languages like C and C++ is that function calls are bound at compile-time. This leads to faster execution, but less dynamic behaviour. Objective C uses dynamic (or late) binding -- whereby the destination of messages is worked out at run time. Such a system invariably involves less type checking at compile time, but allows for more dynamic coding and allows some interesting [meta programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming). The dynamicism of messaging allows for some interesting concepts such as Objective C [categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Categories), whereby you can replace functionality of arbitrary classes with your own implementations. This is similar to subclassing, but not the same; for example, a category can't have its own data; it runs in effect as part of the class you are categorizing.

The features of messaging can lead to more succinct code. For example, in Objective C you can send any message to `nil`, and the system will do nothing and just continue:

```
NSObject *thing = nil;
[thing someMessage];  // does nothing. No need for nil check!
```

Other languages without this feature (e.g. C++, Java) can use a design pattern called [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) to achieve the same sort of effect -- but this requires implementation (whereby you actually create a stub object that does nothing when methods are called).

Comment: so its possible in Objective-C to send a message to an object even if the object has no stub to perform anything once receive that message? Almost like if a program called a function of an object even though the function did not exist? If this is true it seems like this would have the opposite effect of the intended 'increased readability'.